# Filter by monthday Pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, filter, filtering

I would like to filter a pandas dataframe between months for a number of years.

I have a dataframe with data from 2000-2016, and I want to filter between October 22nd and November 15th for each of the years.

To keep this simple let's say I have 4 columns.  The date index, the month index, the day index, and price.

What I have attempted so far is to concatenate the month column and the day column. Ie. October 22 becomes 1022 and November 15th becomes 1115.

The problem arises when I look at dates before #10.  Ie. November first is 111 rather that 1101.

So when I do a conditional filter specifying df['monthday'] > 1015 & df['monthday'] < 1115 it entirely fails to capture all the November dates from November first to November 9th because 111 through to 119 < 1015.

I have also tried to compare this number as a string, so I have succesfully converted 111 to str(1101).  But then this is not comparable to int(1101).

This is a seemingly easy problem that I have had no luck solving.  Any help is appreciated.

Code snippets below.  Thank you,

```
df = web.DataReader('SPY', 'yahoo',datetime.datetime(2015 ,1, 1), 
datetime.datetime.today())

#this adds zeroes but really doesn't help me
df['Day of Month'] = df['Day of Month'].astype(str).str.zfill(2)
df['month'] = df['month'].astype(str).str.zfill(2)

#This one converts it to str but can't compare str to int
df['monthday'] = df['month'].map(str) + df['Day of Month'].map(str) 

#This one converts it to a # but can't use 111 as November 1st because it is 
#smaller than 1015 ie October 15th and I want to filter between those dates.
df['monthday'] = pd.to_numeric(df.monthday, errors='coerce')

#here is where I attempt my intermonth filter for each year since 2000
df = df[(df['month'] >= 10) & (df['month'] <= 11) & (df['monthday'] >= 1021)  
& (df['monthday'] <=1115)]
```

Thank you for your support.

Comment: You can append a 0 at the start if the size is < 2.

Comment: I have appended as per this code: df['Day of Month'] = df['Day of Month'].astype(str).str.zfill(2).  However I cannot compare str to int.

Comment: You can still compare string numbers... lexicographically, so cast everything to string and compare.

Comment: Updated the code to reflect where I add 0's to the code.

Comment: Thank you if you could provide a bit more detail this would be very helpful

Comment: Perform zfill on the Day Of Month column too. You can then use `pd.to_numeric` with `format='%m%d'`

Comment: Thanks I was able to solve it.

Comment: Shall I post an answer, or will you?

Answer (score 0):

```
dfperiod = df[(df['month'] >= '10') & (df['month'] <= '11') & (df['monthday'] 
>= '1021')  & (df['monthday'] <='1115')]
```